# How to have Resilient automatically resubmit a rate limited request

Tags: node.js

I'm using Resilient in NodeJS, in a server-side service on multiple machines.

One of the APIs that the Resilient client calls is subject to rate limiting.  A request that was subject to rate limiting receives a specific header/value in the response, so it's easy to tell when this has occurred.

Is there a way to leverage the existing features of Resilient so that if a response is received with the rate limited header, the Resilient client will reissue the request (with a slight pause/delay)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The committer for Resilient just published an upgrade, now at v0.3.1, which supports a more flexible fail strategy, meaning one can now flag a response as being failed based on a custom function.